# Multicast client keeps leaving group every 5 seconds

Tags: multicast, igmp

I have 2 HP DL360P Gen10 with a Windows 10 VM (IP 10.10.1.1) inside it. It is trying to join a multicast group (228.40.0.227). However, based on the wireshark capture (image below), this client is leaving the multicast group every 5 seconds. I have attempted to upgrade the IGMP from version 2 to version 3 using the method described in this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1190375/windows-multicast-using-igmpv3-in-igmpv2-environme, but it did not help.

This is all setup locally & I have checked the following :

Windows Firewall Disabled No IGMP Snooping on Switch Client is able to send a ping to the server sending the multicast messages & a static rp has configured the gateway router of this client as rendezvous point, so network seems to be fine. My second HP DL360P Gen10 client (IP 10.137.116.1) is able to join its multicast group without immediately leaving. (Both of them are receiving from a different multicast address) I have setup unicast routing prior to this, but it is my first time attempting multicast routing. Could someone advise me on how I could further investigate / resolve this issue of my client leaving the multicast group every 5 seconds?

[WS1 - Client keeps leaving group on IGMPv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMKC1.png)
[WS2 - Client keeps leaving group on IGMPv3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t9hdg.png)
[WS3 - Different client, does not leave group on IGMPv2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbAHF.png)